# How to load struct values into collectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, struct, collectionview

How to load struct values into collection view cell.

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let id,name,age,gender: String
}
```

Adding Value to Person List

```
func addValues () -> [Person]{
  person =[(Person(id:"0",name:"abcd",age:"27":gender:"male"))]

}
```

InSide CollectionView Controller

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
    cell.personImg!.image = UIImage.init(named:personList.imageImage[indexPath.row])

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell.lbl_CompletionName!.text = person[0].id
        break
    case 1:
        cell.lbl_CompletionName!.text = person[0].name
        break
    case 2:
        cell.lbl_CompletionName!.text = person[0].age
        break
    case 3:
        cell.lbl_CompletionName!.text = person[0].gender
        break
    default: break

    }

    return cell

    }
```

its get only **id** value how need to assign next value like name, age,gender once indexpath.row incremented.

The above code works to extract Struct values which stored in arraylist.

Which I do not like the way I written the code.
Is there an alternative way to extract struct values which added into array list property and load it in collectionview?

Comment: Do you have an array of `Person` objects?

Comment: No! not an array

Comment: *How* do you populate *struct values*? And what is `personList`? You need a data source array.

Comment: @vadian since Structs are value types It may have provision to get list of values without assigning to an array.

Comment: To drive a collection view you do need a data source (array).

Comment: Even I set to array var person : [Person]!  at iteration its say person[indexPath.row].id .....?

Comment: @vadian I have updated my question!  If it looks to you code review!  please let me know how can I share my original code in code review?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Person` variable in the `CustomCollectionViewCell`, and set the `cell.person` variable in the `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`. You also need to have an array (in the case below I called it `people`) that stores all the `Person` objects wherever you are displaying the collection view (most likely the view controller).

Example:

**Person**

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let id,name,age,gender: String
}
```

**Collection View Cell**

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

     // Create a Person variable
     var person: Person? {
          didSet {
               guard let person = person else { return }
               // Do something (e.x. set imageView.image = person.image)
          }
     }

}
```

**Collection View**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let person = people[indexPath.item]  // This is the array of Persons you need in your view controller
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
   cell.person = person
   return cell

}
```